# How to access last element of a multi-index dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with IDs and timestamps as a multi-index. The index in the dataframe is sorted by IDs and timestamps and I want to pick the lastest timestamp for each IDs. for example:

```
IDs    timestamp     value
0      2010-10-30     1
       2010-11-30     2
1      2000-01-01     300
       2007-01-01     33
       2010-01-01     400
2      2000-01-01     11
```

So basically the result I want is

```
IDs    timestamp    value
0      2010-11-30   2
1      2010-01-01   400
2      2000-01-01   11
```

What is the command to do that in pandas?

Answer (score 5):

Given this setup:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

content = io.BytesIO("""\
IDs    timestamp     value
0      2010-10-30     1
0      2010-11-30     2
1      2000-01-01     300
1      2007-01-01     33
1      2010-01-01     400
2      2000-01-01     11""")

df = pd.read_table(content, header=0, sep='\s+', parse_dates=[1])
df.set_index(['IDs', 'timestamp'], inplace=True)
```

using `reset_index` followed by `groupby`

```
df.reset_index(['timestamp'], inplace=True)
print(df.groupby(level=0).last())
```

yields

```
              timestamp  value
IDs                           
0   2010-11-30 00:00:00      2
1   2010-01-01 00:00:00    400
2   2000-01-01 00:00:00     11
```

This does not feel like the best solution, however. There should be a way to do this without calling `reset_index`...

---

As you point out in the comments, `last` ignores NaN values. To not skip NaN values, you could use `groupby/agg` like this:

```
df.reset_index(['timestamp'], inplace=True)
grouped = df.groupby(level=0)
print(grouped.agg(lambda x: x.iloc[-1]))
```

Comment: problem with this solution is that last() ignores NANs. So if you are last row has a NAN its ignored.

Comment: it definitely seems like the `reset_index` should be avoidable but maybe its not.

Answer (score 4):

One can also use

```
df.groupby("IDs").tail(1)
```

This will take the last row of each label in level "IDs" and will not ignore `NaN` values.